# Why does VLookUp keep returning Error 2042?

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

Probably that´s not the smartest way to convert "Jan" to "1" from a date like Jan 01, 2021", but why does VLookUp keep returning Error 2042?

```
Option Explicit

Dim MonthMatrix(0 To 1, 0 To 11 As Variant

MonthMatrix(0, 0) = "Jan"
MonthMatrix(1, 0) = 1
MonthMatrix(0, 1) = "Feb"
MonthMatrix(1, 1) = 2
MonthMatrix(0, 2) = "Mar"
MonthMatrix(1, 2) = 3
MonthMatrix(0, 3) = "Apr"
MonthMatrix(1, 3) = 4
MonthMatrix(0, 4) = "May"
MonthMatrix(1, 4) = 5
MonthMatrix(0, 5) = "Jun"
MonthMatrix(1, 5) = 6
MonthMatrix(0, 6) = "Jul"
MonthMatrix(1, 6) = 7
MonthMatrix(0, 7) = "Aug"
MonthMatrix(1, 7) = 8
MonthMatrix(0, 8) = "Sep"
MonthMatrix(1, 8) = 9
MonthMatrix(0, 9) = "Oct"
MonthMatrix(1, 9) = 10
MonthMatrix(0, 10) = "Nov"
MonthMatrix(1, 10) = 11
MonthMatrix(0, 11) = "Dec"
MonthMatrix(1, 11) = 12

month = "Sep"
month_number = Application.VLookup(month, MonthMatrix, 1, False)
```

Comment: `MonthMatrix` has 2 rows and 12 columns

Comment: With your current definition of `MonthMatrix`, `Debug.Print Application.HLookup(Month, MonthMatrix, 2, False)` (note the `2`) returns `9`.

Comment: Side note: hopefully you're not recreating the `VBA.DateTime.Month` function. `Month("Jan 01, 2021")` returns `1`.

Comment: `Dim mnth as String: mnth = "Sep"` and `Dim month_number As Long: month_number 
 = Month("1 " & mnth & " 2021")`

Comment: @BigBen That's exacly what I want to use lol Should I check some reference?

Comment: [`Month`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/month-function) function.

Answer (score 0):

There are so many things wrong with this code that it's hard to list them all.

- Option Explicit must be outside the procedure
- there is no procedure defined
- the opening bracket for the first Dim doesn't have a matching closing bracket
- the matrix sets up 2 rows and 12 columns
- with Option Explicit, `month` and `month_number` need to be defined
- you're returning the value that you are looking up

This just doesn't make sense.